# javascript if statement optimization on array-length flag

Tags: javascript, if-statement, optimization

How should I write following javascript function in a better way?

```
  function showIssueCount(issueSummary){
    if(issueSummary["CRITICAL"] >= 1){
      return {value:issueSummary["CRITICAL"], class:"CRITICAL" };
    }else if(issueSummary["MAJOR"] >= 1 ){
      return {value:issueSummary["MAJOR"], class:"MAJOR" };
    }else if (issueSummary["MINOR"] >= 1){
      return {value:issueSummary["MINOR"], class:"MINOR" };
    }else{
      return {vaue:0, class:""}
    }
  }
```

Comment: the issueSummary object will be of following type.
{"CRITICAL": 1, "MAJOR": 1, "MINOR":1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this

```
function showIssueCount( obj )
{
    var priority = [ 'CRITICAL', 'MAJOR', 'MINOR' ];
    for( var counter = 0; counter < priority.length; counter++ )
    {
        if ( obj[ priority[ counter ] ] >= 1 )
        {
            return { value : obj[ priority[ counter ] ], class: priority[ counter ] };
        }       
    }
    return {value:0, class:""}
}
```

Comment: You made a little mistake, the return is an object, you used `[ ]`.

Comment: @ShanShan thanks for pointing it without downvoting :) . made the changes

Comment: No problem, I was about to post the same code but you were faster so upvote it was :)